Error reporting failure to CodePipeline: JobNotFoundException: Job with id 'JobId' does not exist
screenshot 1enter image description hereI am getting error in codeBuild saying JobId not found. Below is the code i am using
`putPipelineFailure(error) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const jobId = process.env.CODEPIPELINE_JOB_ID;
        if (!jobId) {
            console.log("CODEPIPELINE_JOB_ID environment variable not set");
            return reject(new Error("CODEPIPELINE_JOB_ID environment variable not set"));
        }

        console.log('Job ID:', jobId);

        const params = {
            jobId: jobId,
            failureDetails: {
                message: JSON.stringify(error.message),
                type: 'JobFailed'
            }
        };

        codepipeline.putJobFailureResult(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error reporting failure to CodePipeline:", err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully reported failure to CodePipeline", data);
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}`

I am setting codePipeline Job Id as in the below screenshot
I tried all possible ways to set the env variables for codebuild. Not sure what I am doing wrong here

I am passing job ID as input to the codebuild that is as env variable.

firts thing how are you setting up the jobId? are ayou able to set CODEPIPELINE_JOB_ID on time ?
jobId is unique to that specific job within a pipeline execution and cannot be reused or hardcoded across different executions therfore make sure your flow to update the CODEPIPELINE_JOB_ID varaible is working fine.

Hi Nabin, I am passing the job ID as input to codebuild as env variable. I am new to this please ignore mistakes. The ask is if anything fails in the codebuild I want to simply put job failure result to the codepipeline. But I am stuck with job id not found exception
